# Getting the .java from the package name

Tags: java, parsing, classpath, qdox

I'm using [QDox](http://qdox.codehaus.org/) to parse java sources. I have a problem with this interface:

```
import test.Word;

public interface Spellable {
    /**
    * Checks the spell of the word in a given language
    */
    public boolean checkSpell (Word word);  
}
```

At the moment of parsing the Word type I need to know where the path in the filesystem is.
So, is there any way to know that?, maybe using the classpath?

Comment: Do you want the current directory, or the package of the class? The file system location would depend on if it is in a jar file and where your classpath is pointed at.

Comment: I want the location in the filesystem, the class Word is not in a jar. I don't know how to use the classpath to get it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to do this in a nice, 100%-definitely-compatible way.  Java actually tries to abstract you away from the filesystem a little bit through the classpath mechanism.

Nevertheless, you can usually get the file path via the classloader.  First step is to get a reference to a classloader that can find whatever resource you're interested in (usually the classloader for any of your own classes will work fine; if you have a more complex scenario you should hopefully know which classloader to use).

Then you can ask the classloader for the location of a given resource as a URL, for example:

```
final ClassLoader loader = getClass().getClassLoader();
final URL resourceLocation = loader.getResource("com/mycomp/coolapp/checkthis.doc");
```

Now if you're lucky, the URL will use the `file:/` protocol, and will describe a location on your local filesystem.  If so, you can extract this path and use it as the filesystem location of whatever classpath resource you just looked up.  If it's not a `file:/` resource, the class may not even exist on your local machine (e.g. it's being loaded remotely via RMI) so you're out of luck in any case.

If this sounds complicated - perhaps you can pass in the working directory as a system property from your Java startup script (e.g. `java ... -Dworking.dir=$(pwd)`).

Comment: the second line that you wrote is retuning null, how can I do to add something to the classpath?, in this case Do I have to add the test folder to it?

Comment: @Federico, You need to add the parent folder of the test folder to the classpath.